# Cannot send email from server

Tags: c#, email, iis, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to make a .net core application that send me an email from an URL.
It works perfectly in my local machine but when i deploy it to my server IIS throws me the next exception:

> Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.3.1 Insufficient system resources

I don't have this exception when i test it on my machine and the email send correctly, only in the IIS Server is there any configuration that my server need?
here is my code:

**MailController.cs**

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Mail")]
public class MailController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("Send")]
    public string Send([FromBody]Correo mail)
    {

        try
        {
            MailMessage data = new MailMessage();

            data.Body = mail.Body;
            if (mail.BodyEncoding != null)
                data.BodyEncoding = mail.BodyEncoding;
            data.BodyTransferEncoding = mail.BodyTransferEncoding;
            data.DeliveryNotificationOptions = mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions;
            if (mail.HeadersEncoding != null)
                data.HeadersEncoding = mail.HeadersEncoding;
            data.Priority = mail.Priority;
            if (mail.SubjectEncoding != null)
                data.SubjectEncoding = mail.SubjectEncoding;
            if (mail.Headers != null)
                foreach (NameValueCollection header in mail.Headers)
                {
                    data.Headers.Add(header);
                }
            if (mail.Attachments != null)
                foreach (String att in mail.Attachments)
                {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(att);
                    data.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }
            if (mail.CC != null)
                foreach (String cc in mail.CC)
                {
                    data.CC.Add(cc);
                }
            data.From = new MailAddress(mail.From);
            data.IsBodyHtml = mail.IsBodyHtml;
            data.Subject = mail.Subject;
            foreach (String to in mail.To)
            {
                data.To.Add(to);
            }
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("<IP of SMTP server>");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(data);
            data.Dispose();
            return "Done!";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Mail not send: " + e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

also i send this from an HttpClient from any other code...

**AuthOController.cs - Recovery method**

```
    [HttpPost("Recovery/{userName}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Recovery(String userName)
    {
        try
        {
          Correo sender = new Correo();
          ...
          ...
          ...
          var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sender);
                var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
                var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
                byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var result = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://MailSender/api/Mail/Send", byteContent);

                var contents = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               }
            return Ok("Done!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("recovery_failure", "There was an error in the service: " + e.Message, ModelState));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is server related problem

Comment: 'Check the Email server disk space where the transport queue is located (default C:)' https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5238caea-8ea7-40c1-a7cf-ef425e92f084/452-431-insufficient-system-resources?forum=Exch2016MFSM

Comment: yes that is what i think do you know how to solve this problem in IIS? i try to run this code in console and works good too... but in iis doesnt work.

Comment: This probably isn't the source of the problem but SmtpClient implements IDisposable and should be disposed of along with the MailMessage.

Answer (score 0):

data.From = new MailAddress(mail.From); 
this line create new object, Change this
For detail help [check here](https://coders-destination.blogspot.com/2018/04/public-static-bool-sendemailemailviewmo.html)

Comment: Is the same thing, also receive a string.